# Safe Delete in C++

Tags: c++

I have developed an array based implementation of a hashTable with several stock names, symbols, prices, and the like. I need to remove a stock from my array. I am told that using the delete operator is bad object oriented design. What is the good object oriented design for deletion?

```
bool hash::remove(char const * const symbol, stock &s,
int& symbolHash, int& hashIndex, int& usedIndex)
{
 symbolHash = this->hashStr( symbol ); // hash to try to reduce our search.
         hashIndex = symbolHash % maxSize;
         usedIndex = hashIndex;

 if (     hashTable[hashIndex].symbol != NULL &&
  strcmp( hashTable[hashIndex].symbol , symbol ) == 0 ) 
 {
  delete hashTable[hashIndex].symbol;
  hashTable[hashIndex].symbol = NULL; 
  return true;
 }
 for ( int myInt = 0; myInt < maxSize; myInt++ )
 {
  ++usedIndex %= maxSize;
  if ( hashTable[usedIndex].symbol != NULL &&
    strcmp( hashTable[usedIndex].symbol , symbol ) == 0 )
   {
    delete hashTable[usedIndex].symbol;
    hashTable[usedIndex].symbol = NULL;
    return true; 
  }
 }
 return false;
}
```

Noticing that i have a stock &s as a parameter, i can use it like this:

```
s = &hashTable[usedIndex];
delete s.symbol;
s.symbol = NULL;
hashTable[usedIndex] = &s;
```

This does work however, it results in a memory leaks. Even then, i am not sure if it is good object orinted design.

here is my header, where stock and all that stuff is initialized and defined.

//hash.h

```
private:
 friend class stock;
 int isAdded; // Will contain the added hash index.
 // Test for empty tables.
 // Can possibly make searches efficient.
 stock *hashTable; // the hashtable will hold all the stocks in an array

};
```

// hashtable ctor

```
hash::hash(int capacity) : isAdded(0),
hashTable(new stock[capacity]) // allocate array with a fixed size
{
 if ( capacity < 1 ) exit(-1);

    maxSize = capacity;

 // We can initialize our attributes for the stock
 // to NULL, and test for that when searching.
 for ( int index = 0; index < maxSize; index++ )
 {
  hashTable[index].name = NULL;
  hashTable[index].sharePrice = NULL;
  hashTable[index].symbol = NULL;
 }
}
```

// stock.h

...
    friend class hashmap;

```
private:

 const static int maxSize; // holds the capacity of the hash table minus one
 date  priceDate; // Object for the date class. Holds its attributes.
 char *symbol;
 char *name;
 int   sharePrice;
 };
```

My question is still just, how do i preform a safe remove?

```
s = &hashTable[usedIndex];
delete s.symbol;
s.symbol = NULL;
hashTable[usedIndex] = &s;
```

That seems to work, but results in memory leaks! How is this done safely?

delete hashTable[usedIndex].symbol;
hashTable[usedIndex].symbol = NULL;    <-- without doing this.

The status of the slot in the array (empty, etc) should not be recorded in the stock instance. That's bad object oriented design. Instead, I need to store the status of an array slot in the array slot itself.

How would i do that?

Comment: I am not sure about the delete operator, but having tons of const char* instead of strings and the thirty sixt reinvention of the wheel^H^H^H hashtable instead of a map is definetly a sign of bad design.

Comment: Using delete has nothing to do with object oriented design, whoever told you that does not know what they are talking about.  If you allocate memory on the heap you gave to delete it, period.  These days we try to use idioms like RAII to encapsulate the process of managing heap memory, but at some point memory still needs to be freed.

Comment: There is not enough information here to answer the question. The only fact that you manage to convey is: You have a class that can be used incorrectly because you give public access to internal parts of your structure. Thus is the bad OO design. The user of the class should not need to know or be able to manipulate the internal structure or modify an instance that would leave it in an inconsistant state.

Comment: OMG I'm having a flashback to 1992 and it's like the STL never happened.  Like all these other posters say, go and rewrite this in 5 lines using std::string and std::map, and be thankful.

Comment: @timday, he probably *has* to implement this for a class assignment.

Comment: Don't obsess so much over "bad OO design". What you *should* be thinking about is "bad design" period. Whether or not it is OO just doesn't matter. If it is good design, then it is good, whether or not it uses OOP. If it is bad design, then it is bad, no matter how many OOP tricks and idioms you throw into it.

Comment: @Charles Salvia: If so, that's relevant information that should have been put in the question, since it completely changes which answer is suitable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> NOTE: This answer is just addressing
>   some of the things you are doing
>   incorrectly. This is not the best way
>   to do what you are doing. An array of
>   `stock**` would make more sense.

Doesn't your stock class have a constructor? You don't need to know anything about the stock class if it is a proper object:

```
hash::hash(int capacity) // change this to unsigned and then you can't have capacity < 0
  : isAdded(0)
  , hashTable(0) // don't call new here with bad parameters
{
   if ( capacity < 1 ) exit(-1); // this should throw something, maybe bad_alloc

   maxSize = capacity;
   hashTable = new stock[capacity]; // this calls the stock() constructor

   // constructor already called. All this code is useless
   // We can initialize our attributes for the stock
   // to NULL, and test for that when searching.
//   for ( int index = 0; index < maxSize; index++ )
//   {
//       hashTable[index].name = NULL;
//      hashTable[index].sharePrice = NULL;
//      hashTable[index].symbol = NULL;
//   }
}

class stock {
    char* name; // these should be std::string as it will save you many headaches
    char* sharePrice; // but I'll do it your way here so you can see how to
    char* symbol;  // avoid memory leaks
public:
    stock() : name(0), sharePrice(0), symbol(0) {}
    ~stock() { delete[] name; delete[] sharePrice; delete[] symbol; }
    setName(const char* n) { name = new char[strlen(n)+1]; strcpy(name, n); }
    setPrice(const char* p) { sharePrice = new char[strlen(p)+1]; strcpy(sharePrice, p); }
    setSymbol(const char* s) { symbol = new char[strlen(s)+1]; strcpy(symbol, n); }

    const char* getName() const { return name; }
    const char* getPrice() const { return sharePrice; }
    const char* getSymbol() const { return symbol; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're  using (or trying to use) open addressing with linear-probing for collision resolution.  In that case, you need to somehow mark items as deleted (as opposed to empty), so that you can still access items which fall after deleted items. Otherwise, you won't be able to lookup certain items because your probing sequence will be terminated prematurely if it finds a deleted bucket.  Therefore, you won't be able to access certain items in the table anymore and that's probably why you're getting a memory leak.

Basically, you're supposed to start at the hash index, compare the item with your key, and then if it isn't equal to your key, increment to the next index and repeat until either you find the item, or until you encounter an empty bucket.  If you find the item, delete the item and mark that index as deleted.  But the important thing is that you have some way to distinguish between an empty hash bucket, and a deleted hash bucket, otherwise a deleted bucket will cause you to terminate your probing sequence early.

As for "good object oriented design", there is no inherent property of object-oriented programming that necessarily makes using `delete` a bad design.  Every data structure that allocates memory has to free it somehow.  What you're probably referring to is the fact that it's usually safer and less work to implement classes that don't manage their own memory, but rather delegate that responsibility to pre-made container classes, like `std::vector` or `std::string`

Answer (score 1):

To get good object oriented design, a collection should be agnostic of what is stored in it. This really has nothing to do with using the `delete` operator per se, but requiring an object (your `stock` in this case) to store data structure specific code is.

There are two plans things I can see to quickly fix this issue.

1. Use an array of `stock *` instead of just `stock`. Then a null value will mean the slot is open, and a non-null value will mean the slot can be used. In this plan you would call new and delete on the entire `stock` object as it is inserted and then as it is removed, which is more object oriented than just the symbol.
2. Create a `HashSlot`  class that wraps the `stock` item, adding the book keeping values that are needed.
   Your hash table would then be an array of `HashSlot` items.

I prefer the second. In either case, `stock` should have a destructor that clears up its own internal memory.

Comment: I mildly disagree with your first sentence. Agnostic collections might be preferred but Boost.Intrusive shows that sometimes the object knows about the collection it is in.

Answer (score 1):

> I have developed an array based implementation of a hashTable with several stock names, symbols, prices, and the like. I need to remove a stock from my array. I am told that using the delete operator is bad object oriented design. What is the good object oriented design for deletion?

Well, one of the key principles behind object oriented design is **reusability**.

Hence, the only good object oriented design is to **reuse** the solutions that have already been developed for you!

C++ comes with a perfecetly good `map` class. Most recent compilers also support TR1, which adds a hash table under the name `unordered_map`.

The Boost libraries also contain an implementations of `unordered_map` in case you're stuck on a compiler without TR1 support.

**As for your question about `delete`:**
I'm not sure who told you that `delete` is "bad object-oriented design", or why, but what they *might* have meant is that it is *bad C++ design*.

A common guideline is that you should never explicitly call `delete`. Instead, it should be called implicitly through the use of the *RAII* idiom.

Whenever you create a resource that must, at some later point, be deleted, you wrap it in a small stack-allocated object, whose destructor calls `delete` for you.

This guarantees that it gets deleted when the RAII object goes out of scope, regardless of *how* you leave the scope. Even if an exception is thrown, the object still gets cleaned up, its destructor called, and your resource deleted. If you need more complex ways to manage the object's lifetime, you might want to use smart pointers, or just extend your RAII wrapper with copy constructor and assignment operator to allow ownership of the resource to be copied or moved.

That is good C++ practice, but has *nothing* to do with object-oriented design. Not everything does. OOP isn't the holy grail of programming, and not *everything* has to be OOP. Good design is much more important than good OOP.